# Origin and usage of the prefix sesqui.

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, definition, math-history

Last semester I took a functional analysis course and I read about sesquilinear forms, I have later seen the term sesquiregular for measures and graphs. Looking at wikipedia it seems that sesqui is a synonym for semi. Why is this term preferred over semi sometimes? What are the origins of the usage of this prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sesqui-" as a prefix means "one and a half", "more by half" (so $1.5$ times).

"Semi-", on the other hand, means "half" (so $0.5$ times).

It is Latin, likely a contraction of something like "semis-qui".

Answer (score 1):

It's Latin and it means "one-and-a-half times."